# VBA - Copy Values Only

Tags: vba, excel

Following on from my previous question, which was answered perfectly I have now written code for the remaining part of my problem, however I have now developed problems.

Part of the worksheet uses `=RAND()` to generate a random number.  As this is a volatile function I needed to copy the output of the formula to a new location.  If I was doing this manually I would do a copy -> paste special values so that I just go the numbers, and not the formula.

When trying this in VBA I get an *Error 1004* during part of the code when I try to select the destination range for the paste special.

Here is the code:

```
'   Copy Random Questions to Static Page for VLOOKUPS
With Worksheets("Quiz Generator")
    Range("NEWQUEST").Copy
    'Selection.Copy
End With
With Worksheets("Static Question List")
    Range("TOPSTAT").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```

I've tried various ways of doing this, using

```
RANGE().Select
Selection.Copy
RANGE().Select
Selection.Pastespecial Paste:=xlValues
```

Also using:

```
RANGE().Copy
Range().PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

In the original code I can get through to the
    `Range("TOPSTAT).Select`
Before it throws the

```
Run-Time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Pop-up

Any help would be gratefully received.

All of the defined ranges are correct and in Name Manager, and I've tried with cell ref's to see if it was the range name that was the issue.

Annoyingly this worked previously using the long-hand Select / Selection.Paste etc method, but since trying to tidy the code it stopped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, to

- dump the range from `NEWCREST` as values into an array
- dump the array to the first cell in `TOPSTAT` and resize as needed

(you don't need sheet names when working with range names unless you have local range names)

**Code**

```
Dim x
x = Range("NEWQUEST").Value2
Range("TOPSTAT").Cells(1).Resize(UBound(x, 1), UBound(x, 2)) = x
```

Comment: I tried this, but still threw the 1004 error.

I've ended up changing sheets, and specifying the ranges as cell references to get this working, I've got a test copy of the sheet that I'll play with to see if I can get it working with range names.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your file - sanitised if necessary - for us to look at.

Comment: I've uploaded the excel spreadsheet to my GoogleDrive:
[link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1Fh8GIuWP5namVVT0VjNmQ1TGc&usp=sharing)

Couldn't work out how to add to this topic.
Thanks in advance

Adam